# The most [emotional] post about tags ever?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 3 tags containing the word *emotion*:

[emotion](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotion)
[28 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotion)

[emotional](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional)
[5 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional)

[emotional-well-being](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-well-being)
[57 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-well-being)

None of them has a tag wiki excerpt.

I want to initiate a discussion on what they mean, which ones we need and if and when to use them.

I will admit outright that I used [emotional-well-being](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-well-being) sometimes to tag posts. I did so when the question was specifically about it, e. g. an event could impact it negatively and the OP wants to avoid that as much as possible. Examples are [telling a child conceived in rape about their biological father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29186/30519), or helping a depressed [mother](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24818/30519) / [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22317/30519).

I'm not sure about [emotion](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotion). What is that tag about? It appears to be a bit of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me. In most cases, I do not really understand what that tag adds, at all. In some cases, I would have substituted it with [emotional-well-being](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-well-being) (like [1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11799/30519), [2](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/10476/30519), [3](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/6316/30519), [4](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/9047/30519), [5](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/7988/30519), [6](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/5220/30519) and [7](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/4209/30519)). It seems to be used when somehow an emotion is involved (e. g. anger, which has its own tag, or love), but it appears too broad for that purpose. For example, if you worry about your child using their smartphone, tablet, game console and TV too often, a tag like [electronic-devices](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-devices) or so could make sense instead of adding all the single tags, but [emotion](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotion) doesn't tell us much, since they are too different.

There are two cases in which it seems somewhat appropriate:

- [List of emotions to teach](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/18281/30519)
- [Do baby massages improve motor skills and emotional development?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/5274/30519)

I also do not know what to make of [emotional](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional). It has much fewer questions and only one for which it seems appropriate:

- [evaluating social/emotional development](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/4503/30519)

So we have two times *emotional-development*. This tag would make more sense to me, but two questions is not much. I'm not sure the *list of emotions* question warrants its own tag then (one time use doesn't really help filtering questions. Just searching for "emotions" yields the same result).

**Which of these tags do we need?**
**What do they cover?**